# Erro durante a execução do método nls no R - 'arg' must be NULL or a character vector

Tags: r

Quando uso o comando

```
n0 <- nls(Y~expo.der(x, A, B, C), data=dados_Indice, start=start, na.omit(NA), trace = TRUE)
```

expo.der é o nome da função criada que define a fórmula usada na regressão, mudei para MM

```
MM <- deriv3(~(A*x/(B+x))+C,c("A", "B", "C"),function(x, A, B, C) NULL)
```

Sobre os valores de start estou usando

```
             (A)0.9707976, (B)14.50896 e (C) 0.02920242
```

Como pedido anteriormente a saída para > dput(head(dados_Indice, 20)) é

```
structure(list(Y = c(0.504968267320704, 0.580320008623638, 0.591987263077176, 
0.507128952150783, 0.471443542762971, 0.487690808524229, 0.550025947056627, 
0.517020993324232, 0.649271477040753, 0.543409645706519, 0.476085216626585, 
0.420887866612052, 0.587785676649722, 0.546330880659742, 0.598972408502253, 
0.60582105500102, 0.537834815210853, 0.535468008413421, 0.532758019489451, 
0.471561274553937), x = c(20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 
20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20)), .Names = c("Y", 
"x"), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

o algoritmo retorna um erro por exceder o número máximo de iterações. Consultando algumas alternativas, a solução recomendada foi incluir o comando `nls.control` como atributo do método `nls`, o resultado, portanto, foi o comando abaixo

```
n0 <- nls(Y~MM(x, A, B, C), data=dados_Indice, start=start, control=nls.control(maxiter = 200, tol = 1e-05, minFactor = (1/2)^30), trace = TRUE, na.omit(NA))
```

No entanto, após estas alterações, ao executar o comando acima, retorna o seguinte erro:

```
Error in match.arg(algorithm) : 'arg' must be NULL or a character vector
```

Porque este erro é mostrado? E o que posso fazer para contorná-lo, executando a função `nls`, de acordo com o controle estabelecido?

Comment: 1) `na.omit(NA)` não faz grande sentido, omite o único valor passado à função, veja `help("na.omit")`. 2) Sem um conjunto de dados é difícil dizer porquê o erro, por favor edite a pergunta com a saída de `dput(head(dados_Indice, 20))` e os valores de `start`. 3) Em que pacote podemos encontrar a função `expo.der`? Se não vem de um pacote externo, mais uma vez edite a pergunta com o seu código, por favor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na sua última chamada de código:

```
n0 <- nls(Y~MM(x, A, B, C), data = dados_Indice, start = start, 
          control = nls.control(maxiter = 200, tol = 1e-05, minFactor = (1/2)^30), 
          trace = TRUE, na.omit(NA))
```

O argumento `na.omit(NA)` está sendo passado para o parâmetro `algorithm`. Ou seja, o seu código está equivalente à rodar:

```
n0 <- nls(Y~MM(x, A, B, C), data = dados_Indice, start = start, 
          control = nls.control(maxiter = 200, tol = 1e-05, minFactor = (1/2)^30), 
          trace = TRUE, algorithm = na.omit(NA))
```

Por outro lado a documentação da função diz que:

**algorithm**
character string specifying the algorithm to use. The default algorithm is a Gauss-Newton algorithm. Other possible values are "plinear" for the Golub-Pereyra algorithm for partially linear least-squares models and "port" for the ‘nl2sol’ algorithm from the Port library – see the references. Can be abbreviated.

Ou seja, esse argumento deve ser uma string - e não um `logical(0)` como é o caso do `na.omit(NA)`.

Por fim, para corrigir o problema basta retirar o `na.omit(NA)` da chamada da função:

```
n0 <- nls(Y~MM(x, A, B, C), data = dados_Indice, start = start, 
          control = nls.control(maxiter = 200, tol = 1e-05, minFactor = (1/2)^30), 
          trace = TRUE)
```